# Normal Approximation to binomial distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

> A popular fast food restaurant changed their burger recipe in response
>   to concerns about the nutritional content of the food that it
>   previously served. The restaurant claims that 97% of people cannot
>   detect a difference in taste between the new and old burgers.
>
> a. Assuming that this figure is correct, use a normal approximation to
>   find the probability that in a random sample of 1000 individuals
>
> i. at least 40 can taste a difference? (3)
>
> ii. at most 5% can taste a difference? (2)

I started with i. And this is how it went

$$
x \sim b(1000, 0.03) \\
np = 30, \qquad np(1-p) = 29.1 \\
X \sim N(30,29.1) \\
\Longrightarrow p(Z >= 40-30/5.4 = 1.85 \\
Z = 0.0322
$$

Now i can not figure out how to start part ii, could anyone give some advice?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: I improved formatting of your question. Notice that this site supports $\TeX$ in equations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the normal distribution a better approximation to the binomial distribution with proportions near or far from 0.5?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/256357/is-the-normal-distribution-a-better-approximation-to-the-binomial-distribution-w)

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track when you got to $P(Z>1.85)$. A value of 40 people who notice a difference is 1.85 standard deviations above the mean. Now you need to use a table or a calculator tool to find out what the chance is that Z is greater than 1.85

Go to a website like [this one](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-normal-distribution-table.html) which has a normal distribution calculator.

Modify the chart until you get $Z=1.85$, as you can see from the picture below 46.78% of the Z distribution is between the mean and $Z=1.85$. You know that 50% of the Z distribution is below the mean so that's a total of $46.78+50=96.78\%$ of the Z distribution which is less than $1.85$, therefore there's a $3.22\%$ chance that $Z>1.85$

[image: Normal distribution calculator]

You can use this calculator in part (ii) too. Note that $5\%$ of the people means 5% of the 1000 samples, it doesn't correspond to 5% on this chart (that's 5% of the Z distribution)